# Is there a way to have expandable/collapsible json in a node.js cli app?

Tags: json, node.js, command-line-interface

I'm working on a node.js CLI tool that works with large json objects. I'd love to be able to display root nodes and then allow the user to expand and collapse object nodes as needed. Are there any packages available that setup this kind of functionality?

[Here's an example](http://www.bodurov.com/JsonFormatter/view.aspx?json=%2520%2520%257B%2522lol%2522%253A%2520%257B%2522awesome%2522%253A%2520true%257D%252C%2520%2522ithas%2522%253A%2520%257B%2522collapsible%2522%253A%2520%2522objects%2522%257D%257D) of the kind of expand/collapse behavior I'm looking for in a browser

There's precedence for this kind of functionality in modules like [Inquirer.js](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js#expand---type-expand)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a package that will setup completely the functionality you're looking for. But you could take a look at [blessed](https://github.com/chjj/blessed#lists) (a fantastic library for terminal node-js applications).

Look under the lists widget and you have a highly extensible API for creating interactive lists (whether with the mouse, or the keyboard) inside a terminal.

You could use something like the `items` option in the list which takes "an array of strings which become the list's items".
Or, you have the potential to use Blessed's `Layout` widgets which mimic CSS functionality inside the terminal.

With that tool it shouldn't be very difficult to create a simple `JSON` list that's interactive.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for, but it's so awesome that I'm happy to award the bounty. Thanks for this!

Comment: @ZECTBynmo thanks! it's a fantastic module! WOPR or Blessed-contrib are awesome as well. Pretty much cross-platform ncurses in JavaScript :)